# Passing around a reference to a mysql connection in a struct

Tags: rust

So Im trying to make my program create a DB struct that has an open connection that i can pass around as a reference to places that need it. So I have the following class

```
use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::*;

pub struct DB {
    pub conn: PooledConn
}

pub fn initialize(url: &str) -> DB{
    println!("Initializing!");
    let pool = get_pool(url).unwrap();
    let conn = pool.get_conn().unwrap();
    let db = DB {
        conn
    };
    return db;
}

fn get_pool(url: &str) -> Result<Pool> {
    let opts = Opts::from_url(url).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", opts);
    let pool = match Pool::new(opts){
        Ok(pool) => pool,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(e);
        }
    };

    return Ok(pool);
}
```

So when i call initialize it creates the connection, puts it in a struct and sends that back.

```
let mut db = db::initialize("connection_string");
```

Then I can use my connection as follows:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
    struct Place {
        name: String
    }

    let mut places: Vec<Place> = vec![];
    let selected_places = db.conn
        .query_map(
            "SELECT name from places",
            |(name)| {
                places.push( Place { name } );
            },
        ).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", places);
}
```

And this works fine. It prints out the places as expected. But what I want to do is pass that struct around so that a single instance of the database connection is used everywhere a query is needed. so I am trying to do something like:

```
use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::*;

mod db;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut db = db::initialize("connection_string");
    let mut test: &db::DB = &db;
    query(test);
}

fn query(mut db: &db::DB) {
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
    struct Place {
        name: String
    }

    let mut rooms: Vec<Place> = vec![];
    let selected_places = db.conn
        .query_map(
            "SELECT name from places",
            |(name)| {
                places.push( Place { name } );
            },
        ).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", places);
}
```

If I do this the compiler says when I want to use db.conn

```
`db` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

So how do I pass in a reference to that struct so I can use the same connection in multiple places?

Comment: You'd probably be better off sharing access to something with an underlying [`Pool`](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/struct.Pool.html) anyway, as pools can be cloned (creating a second owned handle into the same pool) which will alleviate a lot of lifetime issues. Sharing a single connection will cause you a lot of grief in the long run.

Comment: This was a question i asked on the github discussion just now. So passing the pools is the preference. Is it the expectation that each time you query you open a new connection?

Comment: Whether the pool opens a new connection or not is a detail the pool takes care of. When you borrow a connection from the pool, it will either open a new connection or give you a connection that was already open and returned to the pool earlier. (When you drop a `PooledConn`, the pool reclaims it and may choose to keep it open.)

Comment: But i meant code wise. You still have to call get_conn() each time you want to do a query?

Comment: Yes, or `start_transaction()` (which would be preferable if you are using transactions as the API is simpler).

Comment: okay. great. This is great to know. Im going to try and wrap away as much as I can and needed to know all of this. Thanks

Comment: NP. Note that the way I usually handle this is to have some kind of "db pool" object that wraps the `Pool`. I can ask this pool for a DAL (data access layer) object, which wraps a `PooledConn`, giving me high-level APIs for doing application-specific things to the database, so that the application logic has no SQL in it. This way you get the best of all worlds: the pool and connection are hidden from the application logic, but you still get the benefit of short-lived borrows against the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `query`:

```
fn query(mut db: &db::DB)
```

is being passed an *immutable reference* to a `db::DB`, but making the `db` *variable* mutable. This allows you to change *which* `db::DB` the variable references, by eg assigning to it, but doesn't actually allow you to do anything to the `db::DB` itself that would require a mutable reference (such as calling `.query_map` on the `conn` attribute).

If you change the function signature to:

```
fn query(db: &mut db::DB)
```

you should be able to achieve what you're looking for. In that case, you have a *mutable reference* to the `db::DB`.